# Amazon AWS Request Token From Secure Token Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, access-token, signature

I'm trying to sign an amazon sts token request to get temporary access to my S3 account. I've been following the instructions for Signature Version 4 with no luck.

I am constantly getting this message back from amazon sts.

`<Code>IncompleteSignature</Code>`

`<Message>Request must contain a signature that conforms to AWS standards</Message>`

Here is the url request that I am sending.

```
https://sts.amazonaws.com/?AWSAccessKeyId=**********&Action=GetFederationToken&DurationSeconds=3600&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=4&Timestamp=2013-04-23T19:01:00Z&Version=2011-06-15&Signature=2fc3dc902a20a5aa25c3191f2aa6513088e11596082b6a563b00dc5ea4b8bfa0
```

Following the steps for Signature Version 4 this is how I calculated the signature.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html

Task 1:

```
GET\n
/\n
AWSAccessKeyId=<Access Key Removed>&
Action=GetFederationToken&
DurationSeconds=3600&
SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&
SignatureVersion=4&
Timestamp=2013-04-23T19:01:00Z&
Version=2011-06-15\n
host:sts.amazonaws.com\n
host\n
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
```

Task 2:

```
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n
20130423T190100Z\n
20130423/us-gov-west-1/sts/aws4_request\n
5e769aeb49a050fd7cd1035122712098fd83220ea42a0d9871f0ff2fa622b1c6
```

Task 3:

```
Signature: 2fc3dc902a20a5aa25c3191f2aa6513088e11596082b6a563b00dc5ea4b8bfa0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated I've been working on this with no luck so far. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just making a note here I was finally able to get a token by altering my request. In case this will help anyone else who is having the same problem. I was not able to find much help in the documentation but by continually modifying my request I was finally able to get helpful error messages back from the server. The most important message was the final one which gives you exactly what the request signature and string to sign should be.

This specifically applies to retrieving a federation token from Amazon Secure Token Service.

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

The Canonical String for this request should have been
'GET
/
Action=GetFederationToken&Version=2011-06-15&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAXXXXXXXXXWIQ%2F20130424%2Fus-east-1%2Fsts%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20130424T183200Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host%3Bx-amz-date
host:sts.amazonaws.com
x-amz-date:

host;x-amz-date
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855'

The String-to-Sign should have been
'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20130424T183200Z
20130424/us-east-1/sts/aws4_request
3eb22aba7f25dd4e01be888added6f74db579bdf0d066d2b1f75779a25b1300d'
```

And here is the URL that was used.

`https://sts.amazonaws.com/?Action=GetFederationToken&Name=Megan&Version=2011-06-15&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIXXXXXXXXXXWIQ%2F20130424%2Fus-east-1%2Fsts%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20130424T183200Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host%3Bx-amz-date&X-Amz-Signature=db754013466768c11a86a610796faad6a041bcad9d83f4c958cac82988d2f7d7`

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 does not currently support Signature Version 4.  Please see the S3 documentation for currently supported signing algorithm:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html

EDIT: Sorry for misreading your initial request.  You have a number of incorrect assumptions about the STS request that are causing problems in your signature calculation:

1. The operation is POST
2. The only supported region for STS is us-east-1.
3. The date must be included in the headers to sign

While I understand you may not want to use an SDK, they will give illustrative examples on how to generate the signature.

Below is an example I pulled from our iOS SDK.

Canonical Request:

```
POST\n
/\n
\n
host:sts.amazonaws.com\n
x-amz-date:20130424T164023Z\n
\n
host;x-amz-date\n
HASH_REMOVED\n
```

String to sign:

```
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n
20130424T164023Z\n
20130424/us-east-1/sts/aws4_request\n
HASH_REMOVED
```

Comment: I am using Signature Version 4 because I am signing a request to Amazon Secure Token Services (STS) to gain an access token to my S3 account.

Comment: You may want to consider looking at any of our available SDKs as they all have implementations of Signature Version 4.

Comment: One thing to note: STS is only available in us-east-1, so that is the region you'll want to use for your signature for requests to STS even though you will be using it for S3 in us-gov-west-1.

Comment: I would prefer not to use an SDK. I have changed the region to us-east-1 and am still getting the same error back (Incomplete Signature). I'm pretty sure that my mistake is somewhere in Task 1 or Task 2 because I was able to get the same signing token as the example in Task 3 so I know that my hashing algorithm is working correctly. Do you see anything else wrong in Task 1 or 2 other than the region which I just changed?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a couple of more issues and an example I pulled from one of our SDKs.

Comment: Thanks for your help I really appreciate it. I am going to try modifying my request and see if that works. And I will look at the iOS SDK for examples if I need them.